# Remapping Codeigniter Controller

Tags: php, codeigniter

I've been playing with Codeigniter lately, and I came to know that you can remap a function inside a Controller so that you can have dynamic pretty URL.
I just want to know can the same be done with controllers? I mean If I call `http://example.com/stack`, it'll look for a controller named `stack` and if not found, it'll call a fixed/remapped controller where I can take care of it.
Can this be done?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it can be done, you achieve it by using [uri routing](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/general/routing.html).

In your `application/config/routes.php` you can set your custom routes to remapping URIs.
There are already 2 provided, the default one (in case no controller is called) and the 404 error routing.

Now, if you want to add custom routes, you just add them UNDER those 2 defaults, keeping in mind that they're executed in the order they're presented.

Say, for example, you want to remap 'stack' to another controller, just use:

```
$routes['stack'] = 'othercontroller';
```

In this way, whenever you access 'stack' it will be automatically mapped to 'othercontroller', and if that doesn't exists..well, you get the same 404 error.
If you're hiding index.php from the URL with .htaccess remember to insert it into the `$config['index_page'] = 'index.php';`.

If what you're trying to achieve, instead, is a custom error message when a controller is not found, just override the 404 route as already suggested by @Juris Malinens, using your custom default controller to handle that situation

```
$route['404_override'] = 'customcontroller';
```

Comment: So If I use 404_override, customcontroller will be called every time a controller is not found, right?

Comment: @Bibhas you're right, sir. It acts the same as the regular default message, just customized at your will; it's pretty handy.

Answer (score 3):

Maybe this can help you:

```
function _remap( $method )
    {
        /// $method contains the second segment of your URI
        switch( $method )           
        {
            case 'about-me':
                $this->about_me();
                break;

            case 'successful':
                $this->display_successful_message();
                break;

            default:
                $this->page_not_found();
                break;
        }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use .htaccess to do this or config/routes.php- Codeigniter is very flexible ;-)

If controller is not found use $route['404_override']; in config/routes.php

Answer (score 0):

The application/config/routes.php file would be the appropriate place to do this.  The 404_override mentioned by Juris is only available in CI 2.x just in case you have an older version (I don't know, you may be working on a legacy system, or may have to in the future).

Note, you can do more than just "remap" controllers with this.  The routes accept regex patterns like htaccess rewrite rules; there are also some CI patterns which are basically just more human readable alias for regexes.  Say you had an `Articles` controller with `category`, `search` and `article` functions, you might have routes that looked like:

```
$route["category/(:any)"] = "articles/category/$1";
$route["search/(:any)"] = "articles/search/$1";
$route["(:any)"] = "articles/article/$1';
```

You see how you can use routes to completely remove the controller name from you URLs?  These rules would fall back to assuming the page is an article if the URL doesn't specifically say it's a category page or a search query.  You could then check if you had an article for the URL and display a 404 as appropriate.